# How to make two level select option?

Tags: javascript, html

I need two make two level select option. if selected `bmw` how to show `bmwsubcategory` ?

if select `audi` how to remove `bmwsubcategory` from html and show `audisubcategory` ?

```html
<select id="category">
  <option class="bmwsubcategory" value="bmw">bmw</option>
  <option class="audisubcategory" value="audi">audi</option>
  <option class="fordsubcategory" value="ford">ford</option>
  <option class="fiatsubcategory" value="fiat">fiat</option>
</select>

<select class="bmwsubcategory" name="bmw">
  <option value="bmw 1">bmw 1</option>
  <option value="bmw 2">bmw 2</option>
  <option value="bmw 3">bmw 3</option>
  <option value="bmw 4">bmw 4</option>
</select>

<select class="audisubcategory" name="audi">
  <option value="audi 1">audi 1</option>
  <option value="audi 2">audi 2</option>
  <option value="audi 3">audi 3</option>
  <option value="audi 4">audi 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fordsubcategory" name="ford">
  <option value="ford 1">ford 1</option>
  <option value="ford 2">ford 2</option>
  <option value="ford 3">ford 3</option>
  <option value="ford 4">ford 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fiatsubcategory" name="fiat">
  <option value="fiat 1">fiat 1</option>
  <option value="fiat 2">fiat 2</option>
  <option value="fiat 3">fiat 3</option>
  <option value="fiat 4">fiat 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: onchange hide all elements with the class and show the one with the name....

Comment: i need remove and show in html i don't need hide i need remove  and show again when it is active

Comment: Well hide will remove it....

Comment: Step one, add change handler, and get the selected value. Step 2, find the other selects, set 3 show the one you want. You can do it with classes or showing and hiding directly.... OR you do not show and hide, but dynamically fill a second select.

Comment: how to make with javascript ? i need code

Comment: "i need code" Yes you do.

Comment: i don't now how to use javascript

Comment: Please [do some research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) before asking a question, and [make an attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at solving the problem yourself. Read [ask] for more information on how to write a quality question.

Comment: Are you going to use static data (these makes-submodels will be same all time) or dynamic data?

Comment: if I sign how it works I did not ask the question

Answer (score 3):

Instead using multiple select elements use dynamic select options

```js
//create an object containg  key as category with value subcategory array
var subcategories = {

  bmw : ["bmw 1","bmw 2","bmw 3","bmw 4"],
  audi : ["audi 1","audi 2","audi 3","audi 4"],
  ford : ["ford 1","ford 2","ford 3","ford 4"],
  fiat : ["fiat 1","fiat 2","fiat 3","fiat 4"],
  
}

//on change handler
//invoked when user select a category
function createSubcategory(){

  //get the category select elemeent
  var categorySelector = document.getElementById("category");
  //get the selected value
  var selectedCategory = categorySelector.options[categorySelector.selectedIndex].value;


    //get the subcategory select element
    var subCategorySelector = document.getElementById("subcategory");


    //remove all options for previous category from subcategory selector
    //for removing items you have to iterate from last index
    for (var count = subCategorySelector.options.length;count >0;count --) {
        subCategorySelector.options.remove(count-1);

    }
    
    //set name for subcategory selector
    subCategorySelector.name = selectedCategory;

//if selected option is not the first option (placeholder)
//add subcategory options
  if(selectedCategory != ""){

    //get subcategory options by using selectedCategory as key
    var subCategory = subcategories[selectedCategory];


    //for each subcategory option create option element and add it to subcategory selector 
    for (var count = 0;count < subCategory.length;count ++) {
         var option = document.createElement("option");
         option.text = subCategory[count];
         option.value = subCategory[count];
         subCategorySelector.options.add(option, count);


    }
  }
  
 
}
```

```html
<select id="category" onchange="createSubcategory()" >
  <option  value="">Please Select a category </option>
 <option class="bmwsubcategory" value="bmw">bmw</option>
 <option class="audisubcategory" value="audi">audi</option>
 <option class="fordsubcategory" value="ford">ford</option>
 <option class="fiatsubcategory" value="fiat">fiat</option>
</select>


<!-- You dont need to create dropdown for every category 
    use javascript to create subcategory dropdown dynamically-->
<select id="subcategory" >
</select>
```

Comment: thanks but  i need attribute name. name="bmw", name="audi"

Comment: have updated the code ....     But if you have to send form data to server side use name attribute of subcategory as 'subcategory' and do not change name  for each category .. it will  be more efficient

Comment: i need subcategories in html this code not working for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have nice structure of html, so this is pretty simple, first hide all selects, you can use css, then you can use this JS to show the proper select:

```js
document.querySelector('#category').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
   // get all selects
   var selects = [...document.querySelectorAll('select.bmwsubcategory, select.audisubcategory, select.fordsubcategory, select.fiatsubcategory')];
   // hide all
   selects.forEach((select) => select.style.display = 'none');
   // show selected one
   document.querySelector('[name="' + e.target.value + '"]').style.display = 'block';
});
```

```css
select.bmwsubcategory, select.audisubcategory, select.fordsubcategory, select.fiatsubcategory {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="category">
  <option class="bmwsubcategory" value="bmw">bmw</option>
  <option class="audisubcategory" value="audi">audi</option>
  <option class="fordsubcategory" value="ford">ford</option>
  <option class="fiatsubcategory" value="fiat">fiat</option>
</select>

<select class="bmwsubcategory" name="bmw">
  <option value="bmw 1">bmw 1</option>
  <option value="bmw 2">bmw 2</option>
  <option value="bmw 3">bmw 3</option>
  <option value="bmw 4">bmw 4</option>
</select>

<select class="audisubcategory" name="audi">
  <option value="audi 1">audi 1</option>
  <option value="audi 2">audi 2</option>
  <option value="audi 3">audi 3</option>
  <option value="audi 4">audi 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fordsubcategory" name="ford">
  <option value="ford 1">ford 1</option>
  <option value="ford 2">ford 2</option>
  <option value="ford 3">ford 3</option>
  <option value="ford 4">ford 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fiatsubcategory" name="fiat">
  <option value="fiat 1">fiat 1</option>
  <option value="fiat 2">fiat 2</option>
  <option value="fiat 3">fiat 3</option>
  <option value="fiat 4">fiat 4</option>
</select>
```

the alternative is to iterate on all selects and check if it should be visible:

```
selects.forEach((select) => {
   if (select.matches('[name="' + e.target.value + '"]')) {
       select.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       select.style.display = 'none';
   }
});
```

NOTE: This code use modern features and may don't work in all browsers especially IE.

Comment: Your first code hides the `option`s of the first `select` element because of the duplicate classnames

Comment: @FZs thanks, didn't notice that selects have the same class as options in first select, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the script to show only the selected subcategory and hide the other subcategories like this code if you don't need dynamic data. I have changed some attributes.

```html
<select id="category">
 <option value="bmwsubcategory">bmw</option>
 <option value="audisubcategory">audi</option>
 <option value="fordsubcategory">ford</option>
 <option value="fiatsubcategory">fiat</option>
</select>

<select id="bmwsubcategory" name="bmw">
 <option value="bmw 1">bmw 1</option>
 <option value="bmw 2">bmw 2</option>
 <option value="bmw 3">bmw 3</option>
 <option value="bmw 4">bmw 4</option>
</select>

<select id="audisubcategory" name="audi">
 <option value="audi 1">audi 1</option>
 <option value="audi 2">audi 2</option>
 <option value="audi 3">audi 3</option>
 <option value="audi 4">audi 4</option>
</select>

<select id="fordsubcategory" name="ford">
 <option value="ford 1">ford 1</option>
 <option value="ford 2">ford 2</option>
 <option value="ford 3">ford 3</option>
 <option value="ford 4">ford 4</option>
</select>

<select id="fiatsubcategory" name="fiat">
 <option value="fiat 1">fiat 1</option>
 <option value="fiat 2">fiat 2</option>
 <option value="fiat 3">fiat 3</option>
 <option value="fiat 4">fiat 4</option>
</select>
<script>
    var category = document.getElementById('category');
    var subcategories = ['bmwsubcategory', 'audisubcategory', 'fordsubcategory', 'fiatsubcategory'];
    category.onchange = function(){
        subcategories.forEach(function(value){
            if (value !== category.value) {
                 document.getElementById(value).style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                 document.getElementById(value).style.display = "";
            }
        });
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: i need remove and show, now it is display none; i don't need display none. how to make remove and show only one subcategory ? check image https://i.imgur.com/WWAw9RK.png

Comment: I am not sure why you want to remove other subcategories.
You may want dynamic data, having one subcategory select element to have different options according to the value of category select element.

Comment: im using inside form and data sending in database display none not working

Comment: Anyone can answer the exact solution unless you show the code sending data to database. Your program might recognize the second select, so the other select elements need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `querySelector` method to it:

```js
document.getElementById('category').addEventListener('change', () => {
  debugger
  let selected = document.querySelector('#category>option:checked');
  let active = document.getElementsByClassName('active')
  for (let i = 0; i < active.length; i++) active[0].classList.remove("active");
  document.getElementsByClassName(selected.className)[1].classList.add("active");
})
```

```css
select.active {
  display: block
}

select{
  display: none
}
select#category{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<select id="category">
  <option class="bmwsubcategory" value="bmw">bmw</option>
  <option class="audisubcategory" value="audi">audi</option>
  <option class="fordsubcategory" value="ford">ford</option>
  <option class="fiatsubcategory" value="fiat">fiat</option>
</select>



<select class="bmwsubcategory" name="bmw">
  <option value="bmw 1">bmw 1</option>
  <option value="bmw 2">bmw 2</option>
  <option value="bmw 3">bmw 3</option>
  <option value="bmw 4">bmw 4</option>
</select>

<select class="audisubcategory" name="audi">
  <option value="audi 1">audi 1</option>
  <option value="audi 2">audi 2</option>
  <option value="audi 3">audi 3</option>
  <option value="audi 4">audi 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fordsubcategory" name="ford">
  <option value="ford 1">ford 1</option>
  <option value="ford 2">ford 2</option>
  <option value="ford 3">ford 3</option>
  <option value="ford 4">ford 4</option>
</select>

<select class="fiatsubcategory" name="fiat">
  <option value="fiat 1">fiat 1</option>
  <option value="fiat 2">fiat 2</option>
  <option value="fiat 3">fiat 3</option>
  <option value="fiat 4">fiat 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: im using inside form and display none not working, i must show only one subcategory in html all others must be removed and show after select

Comment: @sityvasaqme If some HTML needs to be removed, then you must store that, so it's not too efficient... And what does it mean: *`display: none` not working*?

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Hope it will help.

```js
function category(value) {
    document.getElementById('bmwsubcategory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('audisubcategory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fordsubcategory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('fiatsubcategory').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById(value+'subcategory').style.display = 'block';
    // document.getElementById('audisubcategory').style.display = 'none';
    if(value == 'audi') {
    }
}
```

```css
.subcategory{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="category" onchange="category(this.value)">
  <option value="bmw">bmw</option>
  <option value="audi">audi</option>
  <option value="ford">ford</option>
  <option value="fiat">fiat</option>
</select>

<select id="bmwsubcategory" name="bmw">
  <option value="bmw 1">bmw 1</option>
  <option value="bmw 2">bmw 2</option>
  <option value="bmw 3">bmw 3</option>
  <option value="bmw 4">bmw 4</option>
</select>

<select id="audisubcategory" class="subcategory" name="audi">
  <option value="audi 1">audi 1</option>
  <option value="audi 2">audi 2</option>
  <option value="audi 3">audi 3</option>
  <option value="audi 4">audi 4</option>
</select>

<select id="fordsubcategory" class="subcategory" name="ford">
  <option value="ford 1">ford 1</option>
  <option value="ford 2">ford 2</option>
  <option value="ford 3">ford 3</option>
  <option value="ford 4">ford 4</option>
</select>

<select id="fiatsubcategory" class="subcategory" name="fiat">
  <option value="fiat 1">fiat 1</option>
  <option value="fiat 2">fiat 2</option>
  <option value="fiat 3">fiat 3</option>
  <option value="fiat 4">fiat 4</option>
</select>
```